# Trying to enable my apps script bot for whole domain

Tags: google-hangouts

I am trying to enable my bot for "Everyone in your own domain". An getting this error.

If I enable it via "Specific people and group in your domain" - it works.

Does anybody have an idea what I missed?

[image: Trying to enable my bot for whole domain]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the HEAD deployment, Apps script bots cannot be shared across an entire domain.

Though subtle, it is mentioned in the docs at https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script.

[Image of description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kFlg.png)

To fix this you can just create a new deployment and it should run just fine.

1. Go back to your Apps Script project
2. Click on Publish > Deploy from Manifiest
3. Click "Create"
4. Use the new Deployment ID for your project.

Comment: Following the "Getting Started: Google Apps Script bot" guide leads to this error (at least today) - https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot.  It appears it needs to be updated to reflect the deployment requirement mentioned in the other guide linked to above.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. We'll look into updating that guide so other people don't trip over this.